# Silverlight page login/redirect/navigation

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am building a silverlight application that needs to have a login page and if the details are correct I need to redirect the user to the actual application. What would be the best way to proceed? This will be my first silverlight app.

I was thinking of having a login page that redirects the user to another page that uses the silverlight navigation framework to switch the content pages after the user has logged in.

Any better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need Silverlight Business  Application.
Template for this is available on VS 2010.
It has login, register user logics, and have navigations.

Answer (score 0):

It is more secure to encase the security into your outer frame window than view page navigation.

A common approach is to have *LoggedIn* and *LoggedOut* states for that view (using the VisualStateManager to change it). The LoggedOut state shows the login panel. The LoggedIn shows your main frame windows.

This way you can reach your site via any URL (assuming deep linking) and still get your security.

Comment: HiTech- what do you use to store the session state of the user? Ie. with RIA it seems to have something called WebContext and IsAuthenticated - how do we do this if we are not using RIA - do we have to use our own solution (like a global bool called LoggedIn?)